# Generating a random sample list from a population that has no elements in common with another list

Tags: python, list, intersection, sampling

I wish to sample elements from a list such that none of the element are contained in another list of specified elements. I wish to keep generating new samples, till one that is non-intersecting is generated. This, code below is what I have thought of, but it's not working whenever there is an intersecting initial sample,it goes into an infinite loop and the print reveals that all of the generated samples are the same.

```
import random 
unique_entities=['100','1001','10001','100001','11111']
pde_fin= ['2151', '2146', '2153', '2135', '2158', '2160', '2137', '2169', '2147', '2015', '2022', '2173', '2028', '2014', '2018', '2009', '1140', '1085', '1136', '1132', '1007', '1080', '1078', '1131', '1106', '1164', '1092', '1108', '1118', '1045', '1051', '1006','1001']
random_entities=random.sample(unique_entities,3) #choses 5 unique entities 
while(not(set(random_entities).isdisjoint(pde_fin))):
       random_entites=random.sample(unique_entities,5)
       print(random_entities,"random_entites")

print(unique_entities)
```

Can you please help me understand what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with the line `random_entites=random.sample(unique_entities,5)`:

- First, there is a typo, you wrote `random_entites` instead of `random_entities`.
- Second, you're taking a sample of 5 elements from `unique_entities`, which happens to contain only 5 elements in total. Therefore the sample always contains the element `'1001'`, the one element which is also in `pde_fin`.

---

Here is a working version of the program, which includes some other tweaks:

```py
import random

unique_entities = ['100', '1001', '10001', '100001', '11111']
pde_fin = ['2151', '2146', '2153', '2135', '2158', '2160', '2137', '2169', '2147', '2015', '2022', '2173', '2028',
           '2014', '2018', '2009', '1140', '1085', '1136', '1132', '1007', '1080', '1078', '1131', '1106', '1164',
           '1092', '1108', '1118', '1045', '1051', '1006', '1001']

sample_size = 3

random_entities = set(random.sample(unique_entities, sample_size))
print(f"{random_entities=}")
while not random_entities.isdisjoint(pde_fin):
    random_entities = set(random.sample(unique_entities, sample_size))
    print(f"{random_entities=}")

print(f"Result: {random_entities}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am really sorry about the typo

Answer (score 0):

You can filter unique_entities, before doing the sampling. Mathematically, filtering before or after are the same in terms of randomness.

```
unique_entities=['100','1001','10001','100001','11111']
pde_fin= ['2151', '2146', '2153', '2135', '2158', '2160', '2137', '2169', '2147', '2015', '2022', '2173', '2028', '2014', '2018', '2009', '1140', '1085', '1136', '1132', '1007', '1080', '1078', '1131', '1106', '1164', '1092', '1108', '1118', '1045', '1051', '1006','1001']
unique_entities_unique = [i for i in unique_entities if not i in pde_fin]
random_entities=random.sample(unique_entities_unique,3)
print(random_entities,"random_entites")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering Maede, but I think this will be computationally more intensive ?. Especially since in the original program both unique entities and pde_fin are very large data sets.